# htaccses RewriteRule not actioning

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying  achieve these clean URLs for my website but htaccess is not working for me.
My URL with one parameter and search input:

```
site.com/page.php?search=some
```

**but  I need**

```
site.com/page/search/some
```

I was tried many ways but not working for me. Is there any extra code needed in the php file?

**Here is my code**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([-\w]+)$ page.php?search=$1 [NC,L]
```

Please help me with this I am new to a htaccess.
Also, I want know how htaccses works with one parameter and two numbers.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/210734/url-rewrite-with-multiple-parameters-using-htaccess

Comment: have you enable use of htaccess on apache2 server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How a rewrite rule works; it has 2 parts:

```
`RewriteRule   1_FIND_THIS    2_OVERWRITE_WHITH_THIS`
```

Keep in mind that you re using plain Regular Expressions in both (a special syntax though) with all of its power.

so in your case probably

`RewriteRule search\/([\w]+)\/$ page.php?search=$1 [NC,L]`

Comment: The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a copy of my answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57666990/6456163). Hopefully it'll help you:

[This](https://grokbase.com/t/php/php-general/0159ts8x8h/passing-parameters-in-the-url-using-forward-slashes#20010509ss83mvqx7894e90njxvrsjgkcg) page appears to have a solution to what you are trying to do:

```
<?
    $Params = explode( '/', $PATH_INFO );

    while( list( $Index, $Value ) = each( $Params )) {
        echo "Params[ $Index ] = $Value<BR>\n" );
    }
?>
```

> Hit this URL:
>
> http://whatever.site.com/ThisIsAProgram/these/directories/are/not/real
>
> You should get:
>
> Params[ 0 ] =
>
> Params[ 1 ] = these
>
> Params[ 2 ] = directories
>
> Params[ 3 ] = are
>
> Params[ 4 ] = not
>
> Params[ 5 ] = real

And to display the PHP file as just the file name, try this:

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]
```

---

If you are wanting a more **complete** example, [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/210766) covers it a lot more in depth than I could. This will definitely help you cover all your bases and understand the issue if my other linked article doesn't make it clear enough.