# How to format URL on Website with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, server

I would like some help in formatting a url so that it is more SEO friendly. So the url is formatted below

```
www.portfolio.com/workDetails?url=work-title-here
```

but I would like the format to be

```
www.portfolio.com/work/work-title-here
```

I've tried the following

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/work/([0-9]+)\.html /workDetail.php?url=$1
```

But I got a 500x error

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://grokbase.com/t/php/php-general/0159ts8x8h/passing-parameters-in-the-url-using-forward-slashes#20010509ss83mvqx7894e90njxvrsjgkcg) page appears to have a solution to what you are trying to do:

```
<?
    $Params = explode( '/', $PATH_INFO );

    while( list( $Index, $Value ) = each( $Params )) {
        echo "Params[ $Index ] = $Value<BR>\n" );
    }
?>
```

> Hit this URL:
>
> http://whatever.site.com/ThisIsAProgram/these/directories/are/not/real
>
> You should get:
>
> Params[ 0 ] =
>
> Params[ 1 ] = these
>
> Params[ 2 ] = directories
>
> Params[ 3 ] = are
>
> Params[ 4 ] = not
>
> Params[ 5 ] = real

And to display the PHP file as just the file name, try this:

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]
```

---

**EDIT**: If you are wanting a more complete example, [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/210766) covers it a lot more in depth than I could. This will definitely help you cover all your bases and understand the issue if my other linked article doesn't make it clear enough.